# Qt does not detect all connected ports

Tags: qt, windows-7, stm32f4discovery

Good evening, 
my project is to create a desktop application.
This application will allow me to communicate from the PC to an stm32 microcontroller via the usb port.

I use the class: QSerialPort available on Qt

I want to know the number of USB port connected on my PC.

Here is my code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>


Int main (int argc, char * argv [])
{
    QCoreApplication a (argc, argv);

    QDebug () << "Number of serial ports:" << QSerialPortInfo :: availablePorts (). Count ();

Return 0;
}
```

So I plugged my microcontroller stm32f4, an external hard drive with a usb cable ...
My problem is this: When I run the program under Qt there is no compilation problem but the result of the debug shows me the following line: "Number of serial ports: 0" Usb ports connected.

Following the activation of bluetooth or the insertion of a 3g key there is detection of these ports, but the others remain undetected.

I didn't understand where the mistake comes from !!

Comment: what is your OS? Have you installed the driver?

Comment: my  OS is Windows 7 . I have installed the driver and the Device Manager detected the STM.

Comment: USB and COM ports are not the same things. QSerialPort work with COM ports. Bluetooth and 3g key emulated COM-port via USB, but STM32 probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Qt only has native support for USB Serial ports. (eg: COM/TTY)

If you want to know low level details (eg: physical port number) of the USB port the STM is connected to, you have to use platform specific code.

[Libusb](http://www.libusb.org/) can help you with that.

Comment: I thought of trying the example of STM32 Virtual Com Port to see if the card will be detected as a COM port. For that I followed this video: https://youtube.com/watch?v=Dy8CcO5i42Y  .But it remains detected as USB in the device manager and the problem persists.

Comment: It will be both seen as "USB" device, and if correct drivers are installed also under "Ports (COM & LPT)". I recommend you reinstall ST's virtual com drivers.